# AEM: Is it possible to test if parsys has content without extending the parsys?

Tags: aem, sightly

Is it possible to test if a parsys has content without extending and creating a custom version of the parsys? Link to some documentation to the parsys properties is accepted as well.

I have a parsys that I need removed in the event that it is empty given that some classes applied to the parsys are affecting the layout.

Comment: I cannot understand your question. Can you please explain more precisely what are you trying to do, what the use case for this should be and probably some of the affected code.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a USE API class for this.

The hasChildren() function referenced above won't work in a js use api class (which is very annoying -- here's the implementation of resource available in the js usp api: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/sling/trunk/bundles/scripting/javascript/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/javascript/wrapper/ScriptableResource.java?revision=1674092&view=markup).

Here is a solution that uses the ResourceUtils.js and q.js to test to see if a provided parsys exists:

sightly:

```
<div data-sly-use.hasChildren="${'hasChildren.js' @ parsys='MainContent', page=currentPage}" data-sly-unwrap>
  <div data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit || hasChildren}" data-sly-unwrap>
      <div data-sly-resource="${'MainContent' @ resourceType='foundation/components/parsys'}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

hasChildren.js

```
"use strict";
use(["/libs/wcm/foundation/components/utils/ResourceUtils.js", "/libs/sightly/js/3rd-party/q.js"], function (ResourceUtils, Q) {

    var childPromise = Q.defer();

    if(this.page.getContentResource(this.parsys) != null) {
        ResourceUtils.getResource(this.page.getContentResource(this.parsys).getPath()).then(function(res) { 
            res.getChildren().then(function (childItems) {
                return childPromise.resolve(childItems.length > 0);
            }, function (error) {
            });
        }, function (error) {
        });
        return childPromise.promise;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the sling resource of the parsys and then check if it has children:

```
boolean isParsysEmpty = !resourceResolver.resolve("/path/to/your/parsys").hasChildren();
```

See the JavaDoc:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-0/develop/ref/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource.html#hasChildren%28%29